# Delete Sync between searchResultsTableView and mainTableView

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a simple question and I am looking for most efficient way to deal with this.

I have a main table (say mainTableView) and it has search bar controlled by searchResultsTableView.

My main table has a mutable array say mainItems of say 10 items.

When search is performed, the searchResultsTableView may contain say 3 items in different mutable array say searchedItems

now in that search controller I deleted 2 out of 3 items and I also delete from searchedItems and searchResultsTableView. These are delete 1 at a time.

So as I delete from searchedItems I also needs to delete from mainItems to keep in sync but the index would keep changing for every delete in mainItems so how do I know the original index to be deleted in mainItems?

Should I look for some dictionary based approach instead of array?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you compare the objects inside array and remove using index.

Say like this, if the item deleted from `searchedItems`  is `deletedObj`

```
int indexToDelete = -1;
for(i=0; i<[mainItems length]; i++){
   Object * myMainObj = mainItems[i];
   if (myMainObj isEqual:deletedObj) //this will work depends on the object inside your datasource
   {
      indexToDelete = i;
      break;
   }
}
if(indexToDelete != -1){
   [mainItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexToDelete];
}
```

Comment: This will work but I am sure this is one of the most inifficient way of doing it.

Comment: Then I think, you can use dictionary as you suggested and just remove the same key from both searchItems and mainItems. Should work!